# Schedulers.io creates hundreds of RxCachedThreadSchedulers

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I use RxJava in my android app and it ran into OutOfMemoryError several times. I checked it with Device Manager and I just noticed, that I have more, than 200 threads, most of them in wait state and usually those are RxCachedThreadSchedulers. The OOMError is raised becaused of having too many threads.
I also noticed, that if I push a button, which invokes a service and get a token and caches it, the thread count grows by 5!

So, I googled and found, that Schedulers.io can create unlimited threads. When I replace every Schedulers.io with Schedulers.computation, the problem goes away, but that makes no sense, since I use the Schedulers.io like it is supposed to be used.

So how can I use Schedulers.io and make sure, that it does not create too many threads?

**Update**

I do the unsubscribing like this:

```
    final Scheduler.Worker worker = Schedulers.io().createWorker();
    worker.schedule(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            long last = lastServerCommunication.getMillis();
            LongPreference pref = new LongPreference(mSharedPreferences, PREF_KEY_LAST_SERVER_COMMUNICATION);
            pref.set(last);
            worker.unsubscribe();
        }
    });
```

**Update #2**

Regular way I use Schedulers.io are e.g:

```
public Observable<Scenario> load() {
    return Observable
            .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Scenario>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Scenario> subscriber) {
                    try {
                        Scenario scenario = mGson.fromJson(mSharedPreferences.getString("SCENARIO", null), Scenario.class);
                        subscriber.onNext(scenario);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        subscriber.onError(new Throwable());
                    }
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

And:

```
    mSomeSubscription = mSomeManager.readFromDatabase()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<SomeEntry>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() { }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // some logging
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<SomeEntry> Entries) {
                    // Some action
                }
            });
```

Comment: These use cases don't seem to be susceptible to leaks. You may want to check if you are using the latest RxJava because RxAndroid's dependency tends to lag behind: you need to manually override it if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found the reason. See the description, **Update #2**:

```
return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Something>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Something> subscriber) {
                try {
                  // Some action
                    subscriber.onNext(scenario);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(new Throwable());
                }
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

When you create cold Observable sequences like this you have to make sure, that you call onCompleted on the subscribers, see above `subscriber.onCompleted();`.
Well, It wasn't there at some places in the code, so io threads were generated.

Many thanks **akarnokd** for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Schedulers.io().createWorker()` you have to `unsubscribe()` the `Worker` once you have finished. Regular RxJava operators shouldn't leak any workers and thus threads.

Comment: I use unsubscribe when I create workers and still threads are generated and not released. That's why I think, that normal `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` will leak threads.

Comment: What is your operator chain and your code where you do the unsubscribe?

Comment: My guess is that the action crashes with some RuntimeException before the unsubscribe call. Add a try-catch-finally to see if this happens.

Comment: It does not happen unfortunately. The leak is from the regular operators. But I don't know what to do with them, because those are cold observables where I use this and it executes onCompleted, which unsubscribes automatically, right?

Comment: What are these operators? Could you create an unit test that demonstrates the leaks. Do you use `unsafeSubscribe()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: I don't use `unsafeSubscribe()` anywhere, so that is definitely not the problem.

Comment: Updated description for regular uses.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome,if you do not invoke onComplete method then the thread(created by `Schedulers.io()`) will keeps wait and exists for those cold observable.